# Java pattern for extending list for gui usage

Tags: java

I have a non-gui-component that internally maintains a list of objects, creating/deleting elements as needed.

This class's internal list should now get it's own Swing JTable based view with drag/drop resorting and deleting abilities. Also the view should be automatically updated if an element is added to the list from inside the non-gui-component.

Should the list of the non-gui-component be made a new class extending AbstractTableModel and ultimately used as such, or is there a pattern in Java that allows me to keep the non-gui-component gui-agnostic and achieve this goal?

Comment: Please add an information regarding the GUI you plan to use. Swing? AWT? Some web framework?

Comment: take a look at MVC and Observer patterns